# How to prevent iPhone 12 Pro from overheating?

Tags: iphone, temperature

My iPhone 12 Pro (Max) gets extremely hot (to the point the screen dims, and beyond) with regularity, usually several times per day with just regular use of fairly basic apps.

Others have [reported the problem](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251954578) as well:

[image]

Is there anything that can be done to alleviate this?

Comment: Yes I have that problem too, it does get really hot. Not using a case. I find that it does get hot when using the processor a lot (for example share your screen on Zoom while you play a 3D game... that's gotta heat it up.)

Comment: Maybe the problem come from the type of battery used?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a cover or case for your phone, you should try removing them as they tend to hold in the heat. Keep you phone out of the sun and use it in a cool area. You can also turn your screen brightness down some and kill background apps you are not using. If that doesn't help turn off Location Sevices on your phone. Do this by going to settings-privacy-location services off.

These and other options are described [here](https://www.asurion.com/connect/tech-tips/how-hot-is-too-hot-5-tips-to-keep-your-phone-from-overheating/) and [here](https://www.ubreakifix.com/blog/10-ways-stop-iphone-overheating).

Comment: +1 for the suggestions. I don't use a cover, I'm already in a cool area, and my brightness is not high or anything. I do have location services on (I probably prefer that to stay on). So while these suggestions don't help me very much, I still appreciate the help!

Comment: You may check the two links I included. I don't know if they will help either.  You might try turning off location services once to see if that solves your problem and then turn it back on.  This will tell you if it actually causes the problem. If turning off location services doesn't help, then you'll know its not a problem.  Sorry none of my suggestions worked.

Answer (score 1):

### iPhone overheating? Cool for about 8 minutes

**Note:** The iPhone cannot overheat by itself. If it has got very hot, it activates protective measures and, for example, clocks the CPU down so that it cannot really damage itself or other components. The environment has the greatest influence on temperature. For example, don't leave your iPhone out in the sun.

---

The operating temperature of current iPhone models is 0º to 35º Celsius, the recommended storage temperature is -20º to 45º.

If the iPhone reaches its personal boiling point, two warning messages inform about the associated restrictions. First, Apple's smartphone switches off its flash (a precautionary measure that also applies if the LED is used for too long) and reports new photos with the message:

> Flash is disabled. The iPhone needs to cool down before the flash can
> be used.

If it gets even warmer in unfavorable ambient temperatures, the iPhone stops operating completely and only allows an emergency call to be made as long as it is still cooled down to the operating temperature.
In its support document with the code # HT2101, Apple writes:

> To be able to use your device as soon as possible, turn it off, move
> it to a cooler location, and let it cool down.

On average, it takes about 8 minutes to rest in the shade.